# BSOD error on Windows 7 ultimate

Tags: windows-7, bsod

> **BUG CHECK STRING =** DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE
>   **BUG CHECK CODE =** 0x0000009f
>   **PARAMETER 1** = 0x00000003
>   **PARAMETER 2** = 0x85f05420
>   **PARAMETER 3** = 0x82962ae0
>   **PARAMETER 4** = 0x85aa2ab8
>   **CAUSED BY DRIVER** = ntkrnlpa.exe
>   **CAUSED BY
>   ADDRESS** = ntkrnlpa.exe+dcd10
>   **FILE
>   DESCRIPTION** = NT Kernel &
>   System    Microsoft® Windows® Operating
>   System    Microsoft
>   Corporation   6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255)    32-bit      C:\Windows\minidump\111109-22198-01.dmp

This is the BSOD mini dump that I have been getting recently.  I was wondering if anyone had any ideas what would cause this.  I just did a clean install of Windows 7 ultimate 32-bit.  I don't do a lot with this PC.  Mostly surf the web and that's when it happens.  My only guess is that the power supply is failing and I need a new one.  I wanted to check here and see if anyone else had some other idea before I bought a new one.

Comment: Make sure that all you're driver are up to date, and that you have no yellow! in your hardware list.

Comment: maybe you should try this, http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6292/how-to-troubleshoot-the-blue-screen-of-death/

Comment: Did you ever get this problem resolved? Please let us know what the solution was.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this a dozen times and it always was due to outdated or incompatibile drivers. It never had ANYTHING to do with power, sleep mode, etc.

1). Use Microsoft Windows Update, check all critical and look in Optional for driver updates. Reboot.

2). Go to the manufacturer's website and see if they provide Windows 7 drivers. Update everything unless you specifically remember updating that driver with the Windows Update program.

3). If your manufacturer does not offer Windows 7 drivers, there are a couple tricks. You can either google the name of the computer and look for people who have released Windows 7 drivers; visit each component manufacturer's website (nvidia, intel, broadcom etc.) individually and download the drivers for your device; or use your manufacturer's windows vista drivers and pray for the best.

Comment: Just a thought - try to focus on chipset and video drivers first as they are usually to blame for this. I see it very often with Intel ingegrated video drivers... but it could be any of the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on my pc, but doubt its the power supply.

My guess is its related to sleep mode, as I never have issues when working, only when I leave computer - I come back and most of the time I have crash problem.

I am going to try to keep power onto various things and see if that fixes it.